# ¿Como puedo solucionar los 2 siguiente errores haciendo llamadas a metodos?

Tags: java, poo

ERROR LÍNEA 38 DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL COWORKING:

> oficina.oficina oficinaCopia oficina oficinaCopia -
> coworking.main(String[]) static method should be qualified by type
> name, oficina.oficina, instead of by an
> expression(compiler.warn.static.not.qualified.by.type) The static
> method asignarNombreoficina() from the type oficina should be accessed
> in a static wayJava(603979893)

ERROR LÍNEA 14 DE LA CLASE OFICINA:

> oficina.oficina oficinaCopia oficina oficinaCopia -
> coworking.main(String[]) static method should be qualified by type
> name, oficina.oficina, instead of by an
> expression(compiler.warn.static.not.qualified.by.type) The static
> method asignarNombreoficina() from the type oficina should be accessed
> in a static wayJava(603979893)

```
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
import oficina.oficina;
import oficina.puesto;
// Clase principal del programa que contiene las instrucciones.
public class coworking {
    // Procedimiento main del programa.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer datos del teclado.
        Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Creamos, un constructor de la clase oficina y puesto para hacer las llamadas a métodos.
        oficina oficinaCopia = new oficina();
        oficina puestoCopia = new oficina();
        // Según la opción del menú almacenada en esta variable se ejecutará un método.
        int opcionMenu = 0;
        // Se ejecuta el menú hasta que el usuario desee salir del programa.
        while (opcionMenu != 9) {
            /*  Desplegamos las opciones disponibles, 
             *  Si la opción elegida está fuera del rango, repetir la decisión.
             */
            do {
                System.out.println("—(•·÷{ Menú de opciones }÷·•)—");
                System.out.println("    1. Asignar nombre a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    2. Asignar dirección a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    3. Obtener nombre de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    4. Obtener dirección de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    5. Obtener número de puestos libres de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    6. Asignar un puesto libre a una persona.");
                System.out.println("    7. Liberar el puesto que estaba usando una persona.");
                System.out.println("    8. Consultar quien ocupa un puesto de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    9. Salir.");
                // Almacenamos la opción elegida en la siguiente variable.
                opcionMenu = datos.nextInt();
            } while (opcionMenu < 1 || opcionMenu > 9);
            // Según la opción del menú elegida ejecutamos un método.
            switch (opcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                    oficinaCopia.asignarNombreoficina();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    
                    break;
                case 3:
                    
                    break;
                case 4:
                    
                    break;
                case 5:
                    
                    break;
                case 6:
                    
                    break;
                case 7:
                    
                    break;
                case 8:
                    
                    break;
                case 9:
                    opcionMenu = 9;
                    break;
                // En caso de error inesperado, imprimir el siguiente mensaje.
                default:
                    System.out.println("¡UPS, ha ocurrido un error inesperado, por favor inténtelo de nuevo!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Cerramos el objeto de la clase Scanner que hemos creado.
        datos.close();
    }
}

// Indicamos el nombre del paquete que contendrá el conjunto de clases del programa.
package oficina;
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
public class oficina {
    public oficina (){};
    //
    String nombreOficina = "";
    // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer datos del teclado.
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Se usa para asignar un nombre de oficina.
    public static String asignarNombreoficina() {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre de la oficina:");
        nombreOficina = datos.nextLine();
        return nombreOficina;
    };
    // Se usa para obtener un nombre de oficina.
    public static String obtenerNombreoficina (){
    }
}
```

Comment: Los métodos de oficina no deben ser estáticos. Quítales el `static`